# React update state after second onChange

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, onchange, setstate, react-component

I am new in React so it could be stupid question but who asks not stray.

So, when I try to put sth to input, that update after I do it twice

Ex.

// I typing "a" on keyboard

State nothing see

// I typing second time "a" on keyboard

State see just one letter a

Here's my code:

```js
    class Input extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = { login: '', pass: '' };

            this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        }

        handleChange(event) {
                const target = event.target;
                const value = target.value;
                const name = target.name;

                this.setState({
                    [name]: value,
                });

                this.info = this.state.login + ' ' + this.state.pass;
        }

        render () {
            return (

                <>
                    <input name="login"  value={ this.state.login } onChange={ this.handleChange.bind(this) } placeholder="LOGIN" type="text"></input>
                    <input name="pass"  value={ this.state.pass }  onChange={ this.handleChange.bind(this) } placeholder="PASSWORD" type="text"></input>
                    <h3> { this.info } </h3>
                </>

            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: You'll need to be a bit more clear about what you're trying to do. What happens if you type "a" three times? What should happen if you type "a" then "b"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updation of State in react is asynchronous which means if you update the state using this.SetState({a:1}); if you immediately try to get the value by using this code this.state.a, It may or may not updated so you will not get the latest value, So you should avoid it. Instead you can do this

```
 handleChange(event) {
                const target = event.target;
                const value = target.value;
                const name = target.name;
                let stateValue = this.state;
                stateValue[name] = stateValue[name] + value;
                
               
                this.setState({
                    [name]: value,
                });

                this.info = stateValue .login + ' ' + tstateValue .pass;
        }
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if  my answer really helped you to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

If you replace

```
<h3> { this.info } </h3>
```

with

```
<h3> { this.state.login + ' ' + this.state.pass } </h3>
```

you will see that it works as you wanted.